# Add animated gif to video with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need a simple ffmpeg script to add an animated gif to video with given x and y.

Comment: You might want to provide more information of what you're trying to do to up your chances of a valuable answer.

Comment: Use the overlay filter as shown in [How to add transparent watermark in center of a video with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/1109017)

Comment: The answer is already there!